# determining which values or solves solve $y'' - 2y' - y = 0$ for $e^{ r t}$

Tags: calculus

determining the values of $r$ which solves the following equation for $e^{rt}$

the equation: $y''- 2y'- y = 0$

that is my assignment...

how do I approach this? I have no idea where to start we never studied it.

Comment: Plug it in, plug it in.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = e^{rt}$. Find $y'$ and $y''$ and plug them into the equation. Note that $e^{rt} \neq 0$ so it can be divided out. Solve for $r$.

Comment: so it's (rt+1)e^rt - 2re^rt - e^rt = 0

diving out e^rt 

rt - 2r = 0

so

r(t-2) = 0

so

r = 0?

Comment: If $y=e^{rt}$, then $y'' = r^2e^{rt}$.